How to dynamically load locales
Currently I have a default language and other supported languages
const resBundle: LanguageTranslation = {
  en: {
    get translation() {
      return require('../../i18n/en/translation.json');
    },
  },
};

const otherLanguages: LanguageTranslation = {
  es: {
    get translation() {
      return require('../../i18n/es/translation.json');
    },
  },
  fr: {
    get translation() {
      return require('../../i18n/fr/translation.json');
    },
  },
};

Soon I need to add two more locales so instead of adding it manually I would be nice to import that dynamically. This is my i18n setup
const useI18n = () => {
  const [initialized, setInitialized] = useState(i18n.isInitialized);
  useEffect(() => {
supportedLanguages.forEach(language => { // currently I am importing all the languages from phrase but only want to load specific language that I need to support based on supportedLanguages config
        if (language in otherLanguages) {
          resBundle[language] = otherLanguages[language];
        }
      });

I tried doing something like
let myPath= `../../i18n/${initial}/translation.json` // where initial was 'fr'
 import(myPath)
      .then(module => console.log('woo', module)) // I got invalid call

also tried
const myI= require(`../../i18n/${myPath}) // still invalid call cannot transform

Any help is appreciated.
